# Promise returned from play is ignored

Tags: javascript, html, audio, jinja2

I want an audio file to play when an image is clicked. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to detect my audio file.

Here is the image and play function:

```
<img src="static/food/eggs.jpg" style="width:100%" id="egg" onclick="document.getElementById('egg_play').play(); egg_clicks(); return false;" alt="Eggs">
```

And here is the audio file:

```
<audio id="egg_play">
<source src=".../static/audio/egg.mp3" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>
```

document.getElementById('egg_play').play() says that the promise returned from play is ignored.

Comment: You have to attach the id to the source audio instead of its container.

Comment: Try attaching your handlers in Javascript instead, inline handlers are basically `eval` inside of HTML markup - avoid them at all costs.

Comment: The thing is, it worked perfectly with my previous project but this time I'm using Jinja. Does it make a difference?

Comment: @PRAISER i don't understand. if i attach the id to the source audio instead of its container, then how would it find my audio file?

Comment: @PRAISER no, `play` is a method of HTMLMediaElement, not of HTMLSourceElement. What OP is doing is correct. yuyu, can you paste the exact error message you get? What does your network tab says? If you are on chrome, what does `chrome://media-internals` page says?

Comment: Ah, I think I see one problem: you declare your media as `audio/ogg`, but judging by its extension, it is probably more an mp3 file. You can get rid of the `type` and let the server tell what it is instead.

Comment: @Kaiido i've removed media type. still doesn't play the audio and it returns a 404.

Comment: Well you've got your problem: fix the src.

Comment: @Kaiido yeah i know, that's what confuses me because i've placed the correct src but it still can't locate it.